# Storing sql query in xml file

Tags: java, sql, xml, xml-parsing

I want to store sql query in tree format in xml file.I wrote a code which split the code into different tokens and store it in xml file.I am storing keywords like "select",from,where etc as xmlelements and the values of these keywords as textnodes inside corresponding elements.When the query contains single single statement it works as i need.but when nested query occurs i want to store the nested query inside "where" element.In that case the code didn't works properly.I am hereby attaching the code.
Can anyone point out logical mistakes in my code????

Second problem is that when i try to store the xmldata in "CreateFiles.xml" file ,the file is not displaying in the corresponding folder.what is the reason for that?

CreateXml.java

```
    /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Work;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

/**
 *
 * @author user
 */
public class Createxmls {

    public void CreateXML() throws ParserConfigurationException, TransformerConfigurationException, TransformerException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentFactory
                .newDocumentBuilder();

        Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();

        Element rootElement = document.createElement("SQLStatement");
        document.appendChild(rootElement);
        Element stmt = document.createElement("SQLStatement");
        rootElement.appendChild(stmt);
        Element Element = document.createElement("null");
        String tokens[] = {"select", "max(id)", "from", "facedictionary", "where", "id = (",
            "select", "id", "from", "facedetails", "where", "id like 34 group by id)"};
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("tok:" + tokens[i]);

            if (tokens[i].equalsIgnoreCase("select") || tokens[i].equalsIgnoreCase("from") || tokens[i].equalsIgnoreCase("where")) {

                Element = document.createElement(tokens[i]);
                stmt.appendChild(Element);
            } else {
                Element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(tokens[i]));
                stmt.appendChild(Element);
            }

        }

        String xmlstring = "";
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
                .newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(new File(
                "createFile.xml"));
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        Transformer serializer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();

        serializer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(sw));

        xmlstring = sw.toString();
        System.out.println(xmlstring);
        DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(stmt);

        transformer.transform(domSource, streamResult);
        System.out.println("File saved to specified path!");


    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        try {

            Createxmls xml = new Createxmls();
            xml.CreateXML();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Createxmls.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Createxmls.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (TransformerException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Createxmls.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}
```

When i displayed the contents of xml file for the query:
"select max(id) from facedictionary where id = (select id from facedetails where id like 34 group by id))

The result i got

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<SQLStatement>

<select>max(id)</select>

<from>facedictionary</from>

<where>id = (</where>

<select>id</select>

<from>facedetails</from>

<where>id like 34 group by id)</where>

</SQLStatement>
```

The result i need:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<SQLStatement>

<select>max(id)</select>

<from>facedictionary</from>

<where>id = (

        <select>id</select>

        <from>facedetails</from>

        <where>id like 34 group by id)</where>
</where>

</SQLStatement>
```

Comment: Why aren't you just storing the whole statement, with question marks for parameters and then separate elements for the parameter values? Then you can just pass the query straight to `PreparedStatement`. What's the benefit of tokenizing? And what *exactly* is going wrong? "didn't work properly" is not a clear description of the problem.

Comment: Actually i am working on a project "query planning" in which i want to generate several sql queries by analysing the sql query given by the user.For that purpose i am tokenizing the sql query and store it in xml file so that i can access these queries later and generate new queries related to that.Hope you understood.

Comment: Okay - so you should split the problem into two. Work out whether it's the XML part or the tokenization which is causing the problem. Currently we've got 162 lines of code, and no indication of what the problem *is* or any sample data that will demonstrate it. A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would really help...

Comment: There is no problem in the tokenization part.Problem is when i store these tokens in xml file.I have edited the question with a sample data.Please go through it

Comment: Well there are spurious "-" signs in the XML you've provided, and if it's really nothing to do with the tokenization, that suggests it's an issue in how you're using the XML APIs... so you should be able to reproduce that in a simple program which *isn't* doing any tokenization. Currently with the tokenization mixed in with the XML output, it's a lot hard to diagnose the issue. (You might want to consider tokenizing to some class structure first, to separate the two steps entirely.) Also, I would *strongly* urge you to avoid using raw types such as `ArrayList` - always use the generic form.

Comment: I have edited my code.I need to find out the logical mistake of the edited code.Please go through it.When seperately run this page xml file is displayed on the folder but on the previous code it won't display.Sorry that I didn't understood the "generic form" that's why i didn't changed it.

Comment: You haven't shown the `Parser` class, so we still can't reproduce the problem. As I said before, if parsing isn't the issue, you should be able to show a short but complete program which doesn't *do* parsing - it just has a hard-coded data structure. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints. Learning to separate out different pieces of code when diagnosing a problem is a really important skill in software engineering.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again.I have edited the code again

Comment: Okay, that's much better - but now it looks like you expect `where` to be handled differently in different cases. When should it create nesting, and when should it not? I think if you can work out the rules you want to use, it'll end up being easy to code - this is mostly design work, not a coding problem.

Comment: When i use nested sql queries contains 2 or more sql statements(eg:select max(id) from facedictionary where id in (select id from facedetails where name like (Select name from facedetails where name like 'A%'))   .For each such queries i need to append corresponding statements inside previous "where" element,as i have shown above code.Hope you understand

Comment: Right, so you want to add an extra level of nesting for each `select`? Okay... that suggests you need a stack of elements. You might want to consider recursion. (I'm not just going to fix your code for you, but suggest ways for you to think about it...) Oh, and you'll need to work out the *end* of a nested select, of course...